# Unblock/block Google talk users

Tags: gmail, google-talk

Is there anyway to block/unblock users on chat via an interface other than Gmail or Gtalk? I can't seem to find any client which does that.

(Accessible via the web; not a desktop application.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.
https://www.google.com/dashboard/ here it shows you your contacts and it links to http://www.google.com/talk/ or http://www.google.com/contacts

Comment: Yeah guess so. Was looking for something hidden somewhere which I had missed out :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a ebuddy id on http://www.ebuddy.com/ and there delete the google chat contact from your list.

ebuddy is actually in my book the best android/web/java based multimessenger. Oh and its free.